# Copy and Paste from a Website - font-weight: bold versus <b>

Tags: html, css, ms-word, copy-paste

To satisfy a request from users, I told them to just copy and paste from a webpage so they can get data into a Word document.

The web page uses CSS and specifically uses a class that has `font-weight:bold`.

When I copy-paste into Word, the text gets pasted without the bold style.

If I use a `<b>` tag and then copy-paste, the "boldness" is preserved into the Word doc.

I'd prefer to keep using CSS.

Any suggestions as to why `<b>` works and `font-weight` doesn't? And how I can get it to work?

Even doing a select-all of the whole page doesn't help.

Comment: I don't know why its not working in your case, as it worked for me, I'm using MS Office 2010. Make sure you've set the property to "Use Source Formatting" while copying the content from your webpage to word document. Also try using `font-weight: 700` instead of `font-weight: bold`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, this is with "source formatting". tried 700 too didn't work. I'm using Office 2007. thanks anyway!

Comment: Just stick with the `<b>` tag if it works for you. You can still style that with CSS.

Comment: @thirtydot ..... yeah, I know, that's the backup plan.... would liked to have not used it though. thanks.

Comment: @james I tried using IE7 on Word 2007, copy pasting some text from this website works. (I tried "answered 30 mins ago" (or whatever)). SO is known for its good markup, so is it possible that it has to do something with the markup itself?

Comment: @james but it does not work when I copy paste fron FF4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, just use `<b>` or `<strong>` to make the words bold. If they're supposed to bold for whatever reason then use the correct mark-up. You're probably not rolling with HTML5 but the [semantic definitions in HTML5 for `<b>`, `<strong>`, `<i>` and `<em>`](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/) are good to follow. Two birds, one stone.

Answer (score 0):

That is because word just grabs the HTML not the CSS which is - most likely - even in a different file.
In newer Word versions it is possible to select whether keep or not to keep the text formatting. Maybe that might work too!

Comment: Having style info in a different file might be the case, as I tried it using in-line style.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I tried the same on this very site (the text _answered **20 mins ago**_) and it worked for me - text was pasted in bold.

Comment: @Nivas - Just tried the same text from FF 3.6.15 to Word 2007, using Source formatting - didn't work. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try another browser or another text editing software. Both methods work fine for me.

Comment: Tried Firefox, didn't work. I am using IE6 (boo hiss) but corporate rules dictate that.